# Which countries outside of the U.S. already have Freedom of Information laws?

Tags: law, transparency

Given that the U.S. has a history of Freedom of Information laws nationwide as well as statewide, I was wondering whether you could answer which other countries already have similar laws. Those can range from simple freedom of information laws to full transparency laws (e.g. Hamburg, Germany)

At the moment the only other country I know of is Germany and there the law is not nationwide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information_laws_by_country) has a complete list. Bottom line is, 96 countries have some form of such a law, the oldest dating to Sweden from 1766. Most of the big countries have such a law, the exceptions being Russia, Spain, Portugal, and Argentina. Rare to find such laws are in the Middle East, former Soviet Union, and Africa.